# How to get profile picture(Image) from People App

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm tring to get the profile picture from People App. I used

`Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.Contact contact = new Contact();`

I got Thumbnail from propety contact.Thumbnail.

I need to convert this Thumbnail to StorageFile. Could you please give inputs to solve this issue?

And, while using the following code:

```
IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType stream = awaitcontactInfo.Thumbnail.OpenReadAsync();

if(stream != null && stream.Size > 0)
{
  //
}
```

Sometimes I'm getting `RPC Server is unavailable Exception`. Sometimes the streamSize is Zero.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new instance of `Contact` class. You don't have to do that to pick contact from people. You should use `ContactPicker`.

```csharp
var contactPicker = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactPicker();
contactPicker.CommitButtonText = "Select";
ContactInformation contact = await contactPicker.PickSingleContactAsync();

if (contact != null)
{
    IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType stream = await contact.GetThumbnailAsync();
    if (stream != null && stream.Size > 0)
    {
        var file = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync("MyContactThumb.png", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
        // You can also use FileSavePicker to save file in user defined location.
        Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer MyBuffer = new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer(Convert.ToUInt32(stream.Size));
        IBuffer iBuf = await stream.ReadAsync(MyBuffer, MyBuffer.Capacity, InputStreamOptions.None);
        await FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(file, iBuf);
    }
}
```